# Assign a set of tuples values to a True/False board in python

Tags: python, algorithm, tuples

It seems like a very silly question, but I stuck on this.
Let's say that I have code like this:

```
board = [[False] * 4] * 4

s = {(0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 1), (3, 0)}

for row in range(4):
    for col in range(4):
        board[row][col] = (row, col) in s
print(board)
```

I accepted to find that the board get the True values in the tuple places, like this:

```
[[False, False, False, True], [False, False, False, True], [False, True, False, False], [True, False, False, False]]
```

But I got :

```
[[True, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False]]
```

Why ?????

Comment: I'm sure someone will quickly find the duplicate question which will answer all this for you, but in short, you have multiple references to the same sublist.

Comment: Try something like `board = [[False for x in range(4)] for y in range(4)]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Comment: Well found, @ywbaek, thank you. BTW, I think in fact that probably the inner list comprehension was not needed in my above example. But the outer one certainly is.

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate with the link that ywbaek found. [EDIT: seems it's already done.]